# Problemas con los parametros de entrada de Powershell

Tags: powershell

le escribo porque estoy empezando a programar en powershell, hice este script sencillo:

```
function holaMundo
{
  param ([string]$nombre, [string]$apellido)
  Write-Host "Hola mundo, tu nombre es $nombre y apellido es $apellido"
}
```

Y asi estoy mandando los parametros en la ventana de ejecucion de powershell

```
PS C:\Users\US465ZZ> holaMundo "hola", "mundo"
```

pero obtengo como salida esto:

```
Hola mundo, tu nombre es hola mundo y apellido es
```

El parametro A sale pegado con el B, y al final no sale nada.

Cambio el separador en el input, en vez de "," uso ";", asi:

```
holaMundo "hola"; "mundo"
```

Pero la salida me sale asi:

```
Hola mundo, tu nombre es hola y apellido es 
mundo
```

con el parametro B abajo

cual es el separador que debo usar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sintaxis debe ser el nombre de tu funcion, la primera entrada en comillas simples luego un espacio y luego la segunda entrada en comillas simples, de esta forma:

holaMundo 'hola' 'mundo'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]